# Azure Bastion - access VMs across peered networks?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Is it possible to create an Azure Bastion service within one subscription (a hub subscription for example), and connect to VMs within a spoke subscription where the VNETs are peered together?  The peered VNets all exist in the same region as the hub, and Bastion Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, It's not possible.

You could vote up this [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/38002603-bastion-supporting-vnet-peering-for-hub-spoke-de) and MSFT is planning for it.